# Win2k8R2: Printer's queue shows `0 items`, what could be the reason?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

It seems like I can print and see the printers while giving print command from a file.
But when watching the queue it keeps displaying `0 Items`, any ideas?

Comment: Try to reboot the server and the printer if possible.

Comment: Looking at the wrong queue? Not hitting "refresh" fast enough? If it's printing properly, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you're simply trying to verify that print jobs are in fact going through the queue then pause the queue and print something. You should see it arrive in the queue and stay there until you resume the queue.